# What is .data.rel.ro used for in GO on Linux?

Tags: binary-analysis

I'm reversing a GO binary, and I was trying to locate where some symbols appear in the binary. I did the following:

1. Used `nm` on the binary - which did not recognize any symbols
2. Used `go tool nm` - same as #1
3. Ran `strings` and piped to grep - Did not find the symbols I was looking for
4. Finally, opened the binary in radare2 and ran command `izzz~search` and I found the symbols I was looking for in `.data.rel.ro` section.

I don't understand what data in this section is used for in the context of GO. Is this where function symbols that are loaded into the binary reside? I'm not sure why else these would be located here, and also why `nm` couldn't find them.